# Is this async Rails action safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thread-safety, thin

I'm trying to make a rails action asynchronous and non-blocking. I'm using rails 3.2 and the thin web server. Is the following code safe?

```
class AnalyticsController < ApplicationController
  # [...]

  # called by an XHR request, displaying a spinner in the main page while loading
  def load
    Thread.new do
      @answer = Analytic.build_stuff_with_blocking_io # can take up to 60sec
      request.env['async.callback'].call [200, {}, render_to_string(partial: '/analytics/dashboard', layout: false)]
    end
    throw :async
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to do an async Rails action:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def async
    EM.defer do
      sleep 5 # Some work that take a long time.
      request.env['async.callback'].call response
    end

    throw :async
  end
end
```

Make sure you have `config.allow_concurrency = true` in you enviroment. And that you are using a server capable of async responses, like Thin.

If you are using Thin:

`bundle exec thin --threaded start`

Comment: Seems to work even before switching the "threaded" flag from "false" to "true". Since this "threaded" features is still "experimental" and since I don't perform any DB queries from there, is it acceptable to keep the "threaded=false" option?

Comment: Unless you specify --threaded Thin will behave single threaded, hence it shouldn't be possible to have a non blocking action. How are you testing that? I wrote an article that includes a way to test if you are effectively implementing a non blocking action http://nerian.es/articles/2014/08/30/how-to-handle-concurrent-requests-in-rails/